# Application only runs if you run as administrator?

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, administrator

**Edit: This problem only occurs on windows 7 and vista from what I've heard.**

I have a very simple app developed with an external graphics library. If I install this app into a program files directory and run it, it will crash immediately but it works fine normally, with exactly the same files. I have realised it is because you need to run the application as administrator for it to work.

I appreciate if this is a problem directly related to the graphics engine I am using, but I don't really think so (but I'm clueless). Can anyone help me?

**Edit for more detail:**
The application executable and files that are needed to run it are installed into the default program directory - for me, C:\Program Files (x86). If you try and run with without clicking run as administrator, it will simple freeze and say "App has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..." My question is basically, *how can I make it so run as administrator isn't necessary?*

Comment: So was the library downloaded by the administrator and put in a directory other users don't see? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: The application executable and files that are needed to run it are installed into the default program directory - for me, C:\Program Files (x86). If you try and run with without clicking run as administrator, it will simple freeze and say "App has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..." My question is basically how can I make it so run as administrator isn't necessary.

Comment: Is it using dlls? Are they registered correctly. Are you sure that the registry entries for the dlls aren't pointing to an administrator's private directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a program cannot perform an operation, it (the operation) should fail gracefully.  My guess is your application is attempting to do something that it cannot do as a normal user and then fails to check for a return code, and then subsequently crashes.  You need to identify what it is your program is doing that it should not be able to do as a normal user.  For example (off the top of my head):

- Write a file to Program Files (x86)
- Write to HKLM

Comment: I think HKLM writes are transparently redirected for the regular user.

Comment: Yeah - my program is writing to a file within the program files directory. Thanks

Comment: You should write to a ProgramData directory. e.g. use `SHGetFolderPath` and `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`.  As for HKLM writes, I am not sure, but I think the transparent redirection is for the x86 section of the registry...

Answer (score 3):

(Without more details) The problem is most likely related to the fact that your program tries to write into the directory and then excepts the file creation/modification to actually have an effect. UAC prevents applications from writing the Program Files directories without administrator privilages. The solution is to redesign your application to not rely on such behavior or store the files in question in one of the intended locations (AppData, etc. folders).

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on the EXE and go to `Properties -> Compatibility` there are some options that might help. You could try running the app in compatibility mode for a previous Windows version or if that doesn't work at least mark the EXE to run as administrator by default.